# TFS 2017 Update 2 - Use REST API to trigger Pull Request Validation Build

Tags: git, rest, tfs, pull-request

The TFS 2017 Update 2 added the feature for manually starting pull request builds.

> Manual triggers are useful for things like automated test runs that might take a long time to run, and you only really need to run once before completing the pull request

[TFS Update Releasenotes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2#pr)

As seen in 
[Builds REST API Reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#getabuild) I would now want to trigger a validateShelfset Build, as pressing the button

[image: Queue Build for Pull request validation]

would do. 
When I compared my JSON Request builds with the "Button pressed" builds via
 http://MYTFS:8080/tfs/COLLECTION/PROJECT/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.0
 the only notable difference was

```
reason: "validateShelveset",
```

and the parameterlist. So I changed my JSON to:

POST http://MYTFS:8080/tfs/COLLECTION/PROJECT/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.0

Calling POST content:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "id": 2
  },
  "sourceBranch": "refs/pull/26/merge",
  "reason": "validateShelveset",
  "parameters": "{\"system.pullRequest.pullRequestId\":\"26\",\"system.pullRequest.sourceBranch\":\"refs/heads/feature/myfeaturebranch\",\"system.pullRequest.targetBranch\":\"refs/heads/develop\"}"
}
```

But while web-UI started builds are seen as Pull Request builds, and have the reason validateShelveset

[image: Pull Request Build]

the POST started builds are seen as private.

[image]

I even tried (just to see whether using the reason field would be recognized by TFS) the reason: checkInShelveset, which TFS Recognized correctly as such a build.

Basically all I want to do is to emulate the "Queue build" button in a cmdline interface, and when I look at the Build API it seems as if I am doing the right thing; am I missing something obvious? The documentation does not cover how to add the (quite newly added feature) manual Pull request builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, you can use the REST API with **PATCH** method to trigger the Pull Request Validation Build.

1. Use the API tracking tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to track API.
2. Trigger the Pull Request Validation Build with **PATCH** method use the tracked REST API (invoke the REST API directly, no need to provide the JSON content.):

eg:

```
PATCH http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/feb1793b-4d91-4be4-8373-02216ec5c36b/_apis/policy/Evaluations/0891d5a4-fee9-4751-8bc6-ff403c2860f1?api-version=3.2-preview
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry was busy; based on the nudge in the right direction: what i still had to do: 
get the Evaluations, through the call
`GET http://MYTFS:8080/tfs/TFSCOLLECTION/TFSPROJECT/_apis/policy/Evaluations?artifactId=vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/TFSPROJECTID%2FPULLREQUESTID&api-version=2.0-preview`
given you have ID for your builddefinition you look for item->configuration->settings->buildDefinitionId; this should only be for 1 iteam in the evaluations; with this ID you can call the patch.

Where is the button to accept the answer? It seems I am blind

Comment: Ty, just found it!